# PL/SQL Assistance Needed with Trigger

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am in the process of trying to create a trigger that when a record is inserted into the employee table(a new employee), the trigger fires and inserts a record into the employee_dept_history table as 'N/A' (since this employee is new and has no previous department). Also, if a current employee switches departments the trigger should insert a record in the employee_dept_history table and the employees depatment_id changes. I am having problems creating this trigger.I was wondering if someone could lead me to the right direction with my code. I can't get the below trigger to display 'N/A'. How could I go about making this trigger work? Do I need to create local variables for the new and old department?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_dept_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee
   FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
   INSERT INTO employee_dept_history
   VALUES(:NEW.employee_id, 
       :NEW.employee_name, 
        from_department_name (NEEDS TO OUTPUT 'N/A'),
        to_department_name, 
        sysdate);
 END employee_dept_trigger;
```

The EMPLOYEE_DEPT_HISTORY table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE empployee_dept_history
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(4)
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
    FROM_DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
    TO_DEPARTMENT_NAME VARCHAR2(50)
    OPERATION_TIME DATE
);
```

The EMPLOYEE table:

```
(
    EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(4)
    EMPLOYEE_NAME VARCHAR2(20)
    JOB VARCHAR2(50)
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(4)
    HIRE_DATE DATE
    SALARY NUMBER(9)
    COMMISION NUMBER(9)
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** This answer is similar to the other two, but I'll post it anyway because it defines the trigger differently in a way that may be useful. *Please note that I've up-voted the other two answers as they'll do the job nicely.*

First, if you're only interested in changes to the `DEPARTMENT_ID` column, you can specify that in your trigger definition:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_dept_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF department_id ON employee
   FOR EACH ROW
....
```

A trigger can use the "automatic" logical values `INSERTING` and `UPDATING` to determine if an insert or an update called it. You can use the `INSERTING` value to indicate that this is a new employee:

```
IF INSERTING THEN
   -- set old department name = 'N/A'
ELSE
   -- set old department name = whatever
END IF;
```

Your question doesn't describe where the department *name* comes from, so this example descends into pseudocode when it comes to the department names:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_dept_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF department_id ON employee
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    -- New employee
    INSERT INTO employee_dept_history VALUES (
       :NEW.employee_id,
       :NEW.employee_name,
       'N/A',
       (SELECT department_name from ...), <-- based on :NEW.department_id
       SYSDATE);
  ELSE
    -- Existing employee
    INSERT INTO employee_dept_history VALUES (
       :NEW.employee_id,
       :NEW.employee_name,
       (SELECT department_name from ...), <-- based on :OLD.department_id
       (SELECT department_name from ...), <-- based on :NEW.department_id
       SYSDATE);
  END IF;
END employee_dept_trigger;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's either

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_dept_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  from_department_name varchar(255);
  to_department_name varchar(255);
BEGIN
   select from DEPARTMENT where DEPARTMENT_ID=:NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID into to_department_name;
   IF INSERTING THEN
   INSERT INTO employee_dept_history
   VALUES(:NEW.employee_id, 
       :NEW.employee_name, 
        'N/A',
        to_department_name, 
        sysdate);
   end if;
   IF UPDATING THEN
   select from DEPARTMENT where DEPARTMENT_ID=:OLD.DEPARTMENT_ID into from_department_name;
   INSERT INTO employee_dept_history
   VALUES(:NEW.employee_id, 
        :NEW.employee_name, 
        from_department_name ,
        to_department_name, 
        sysdate);
   end if;
 END employee_dept_trig;
```

or I don't understand your question.

Comment: if a new record is inserted into the employee table I want the trigger to insert a record into the employee_dept_history table (FROM_DEPARTMENT_NAME = 'N/A' .

Comment: After reading your question 4 times I finally understood, what do you want. You should have also posted structure for DEPARTMENT table or whatever stores department names.

Comment: Do I need to put the SELECT clause after the INSERT?

Comment: This is very approximate code, as I don't have any idea about where do you store department names. The basic idea is: 1) get name for new department 2) if mode is INSERTING, then use 'N/A' and this new department name for audit record 3) if mode is UPDATING, also get OLD department name and use told and new names for audit record. Now read error message closely (it should contain line number and more detailed info, then you wrote) and fix your code according to your database structure.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employee_dept_trigger
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON employee
   FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

IF INSERTING THEN
   INSERT INTO employee_dept_history
   VALUES(:NEW.employee_id, 
       :NEW.employee_name, 
        'N/A',
        :NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
        sysdate);
ELSE
   INSERT INTO employee_dept_history
   VALUES(:NEW.employee_id, 
       :NEW.employee_name, 
       :OLD.DEPARTMENT_ID, 
       :NEW.DEPARTMENT_ID,
        sysdate);
END IF;
 END employee_dept_trigger;
```

It won't be quite right yet though as you haven't indicated where the department name comes from. I've used department id just to give you an idea..